# Trying to get the multiple text fields from webpage using element.text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to the get the text from a header field on a webpage. However, the field seems to have two separate text values, not one. When I use element.text to access the text, I only get the first bit of the text and not the second part which just so happens to be the part I am interested in.

I have tried using .text to access the text. Using get_attribute('value') does not work and only returns me 'None' meaning it cannot find a matching parameter.

Sample of what the element looks like:

```html
<h2 class="Some-Unique-Class">
"Validate Response:"
"Success"
</h2>
```

I want to see both, 'Validate Response:' and 'Success' but I only see 'Validate Response' when using the .text method and not the 'Success' part.

Environment details:
Selenium Webdriver;
Python 3.5.2

Comment: Have you tested with `.get_attribute("textContent")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's the matter of element location or non-unique match.

For example if I use the following [XPath selector](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727):

```
//h2[@class='Some-Unique-Class']
```

I get the same "full" text for both:

- [.text](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) property
- [get_attribute()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) function when querying for [innerText](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) property value

  [image]

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort on this. I looked at the solutions recommended by @Jack Fleeting along with yours. I was not able to get it to work but the links you shared helped me troubleshoot. Looking at the page source i saw that the //h2 element contained only 'Validate Response:' when loading it using Selenium. Not sure why. I went with a different element entirely for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is, but the following worked for me on your html string:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
driver = Chrome()
dat = [your html string]

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=dat))
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)
```

Output:

> "Validate Response:" "Success"